# Creating a crontab to run Python on Dreamhost

Tags: python, python-2.7, cron, dreamhost

Let me start out by saying I'm extremely new to using python and creating a crontab.

Basically have a custom Python environment created on my dreamhost account using this tutorial
http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Python#Automatic_Installation
Running python script is easy after this. Normally I just type this whenever I have a new session.

```
source /home/emre801/.bashrc

pb switch 2.7.3
```

Then I just run any python script using this

```
pb py code.py
```

The issue is when I try to create a crontab, I have this right now in my crontab.

```
*/10 * * * * source /home/emre801/.bashrc; pb switch 2.7.3;pb py code.py
```

This code emails me the following output

```
/bin/sh: pb: command not found
```

My question is how can I set it up the source correctly to not give me this error?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a bash script for this:

`/home/emre801/run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/emre801/.bashrc
pb switch 2.7.3
pb /full/path/to/your/code.py
```

make it executable:

```
$ chmod 755 /home/emre801/run.sh
```

And add it to the crontab:

```
*/10 * * * * /home/emre801/run.sh
```

or

```
*/10 * * * * bash /home/emre801/run.sh
```

Comment: cron uses a very simple and limited shell (usually not bash, in this case `/bin/sh`), so that's why using this script would solve the problem-- the shebang line forces it to be interpreted with the bash shell instead of the cron shell.